# How can I make real time checking input sections in Django forms

Tags: django

I don't know how to call it exactly, but what I wanna make is when I input something in `website` attribute in the model below, I want the input section to notify me if it already exists or not. It must check the existence every time I input a character by a character because it's a waste of time to notify me about existence after filling in all the input sections other than the `website` attribute.

Does Django forms or something already support this feature? If not, can anyone guide me an efficient way to implement this feature?

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ...
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

**views.py**

```
class StoreCreateView(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model=Store
    template_name='cms/store_new.html'
    fields='__all__'
    success_url=reverse_lazy('cms:store')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        val = request.GET.get('val')
        exist = Store.objects.filter(website__iexact=val).exists()
        # return HttpResponse({'exist':exist})
        return render(request, 'cms/store_new.html', {'exist': exist})

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

Comment: By performing AJAX calls, and those could then response with for example a JSON object that specifies what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, you need to this with AJAX, here's an example: Listen to any events of the targeted input.

```
$(document).on("keypress",'id_input',function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"",
        type:"GET",
        data:{        
            val:val,
        },
        success:function(data){
            if(data.exist)
                alert('Already Exist')
        },
    });
});
```

Then in your view, you need to retrieve the data and check whether it exists, and return Json Response

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class StoreCreateView(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model=Store
    template_name='cms/store_new.html'
    fields='__all__'
    success_url=reverse_lazy('cms:store')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            val = request.GET.get('val')
            exist = Store.objects.filter(website__iexact=val).exists()
            return HttpResponse({'exist':exist})
            return JsonResponse({'exist':exist})
        return render(request, 'cms/store_new.html', {'exist': exist})

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer! I have a problem by the way. So, I made `get()` to get the passed value from Ajax in views.py. But, `JsonResponse()` opens a new blank showing just {'exist':exist}. Should I use another function other than 'get()' to pass back the data to the template level?

Comment: Parse the data with `JSON.parse()`, and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

Comment: Hmm, still confused. Shouldn't `JSON.parse()` be used in JavaScript side? I mean the problem happens in Django views.py, but I don't understand what `JSON.parse()` can do here. By the way, I tried using 'render()', but it breaks the form from `CreateView` of Django generic.

Comment: Correct, I thought you were talking about the js side, it's showing just {'exist':exist} because you access the view directly, you shoudn't, let AJAX do it

Comment: I updated my answer to make it fit to your view.. NOTE, this is not `HttpReponse`, but rather a `JsonReponse`. Also you  need to check if it's an `Ajax` request